# How to get text from invisible element

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the text of an invisible element, when I try to get it, it gives me nothing when printing it. I ensured that this element is not in a different `iframe`. Can any one help me?

Code for getting the element's text:

```
text = self.dataBrowser.find_element('xpath', '//div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your element is hidden, i.e. (element is present in the DOM but not visible) and you are trying to extract its text.
For this, you may apply `execute_javascript`.

```
txt =  self.dataBrowser.find_element('xpath', '//div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
x = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", txt)
print(x)
```

Comment: can you define your driver var

Comment: 'cause there is nothing in python's driver object called execute_javascript

Comment: do you mean execute_script ?

Comment: it worked, can you edit your answer so that anyone can understand it?

Comment: @OmarYacop Thanks for the correction. I actually typed everything here directly without actually subjecting it to test or use of an IDE, and hence the mistake. I have corrected my answer now.